# TeamCity agent as service vs TeamCity agent not as service

Tags: teamcity, agent

Could anybody explain difference? When during installation I install teamcity like service I see teamcity agent service running.

What if agent installed without "as service" checkbox? How it will works? does it mean that I should start service manualy and thats all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the TeamCity build agent as a service, then it will automatically start when the system starts.

If you do not, you will need to manually start it every time the system starts.

Comment: Why should you "start it every time the system starts"? Why not just when you need it? :)

Comment: @TheincredibleJan The point of a CI server is normally that it runs builds automatically (e.g. on every push, or every night). If you have to start it manually each time that somewhat defeats the point

Comment: It has been my experience that automatic builds only encourage some overzealous QA colleagues to do unnecessary testing. I have now uninstalled the BuildAgent service and start the thing with the attached batch when I have decided that there is something to test or a stable build can be made. For me, the point of the build server is to automatically version and create and keep delivery packages. I can't see any deeper sense in nightly builds.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Good for you?